# Run-time error '438'

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm aware that there are several posts regarding this Run-time error '438', but I still can't figure out how to fix this. This is my entire code: https://pastebin.com/S6LigcWz but the part in question is this:

```
With c.ChartData
    .Activate
    .Workbooks.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Clear
    .Workbooks.Sheets(1).Range(A2).Select
    .Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .Workbooks.Close
End With
```

This code starts in ppt then goes into excel and copies a range then "tries" to paste into a chart in ppt. This is the part of the code where it's trying to paste into the chart, and the part where the error occurs. It errors on `.Workbooks.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Clear`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you executing this in PowerPoint or Excel?

Comment: Where is your object reference to Powerpoint?

Comment: I am executing in ppt. So the macro has references to excel instead. @jcarroll

Comment: Try taking the dots off the beginning of the `Workbooks`

Comment: @DaBeau96 oh, good eye! post that as an answer - `ChartData` definitely doesn't have a `Workbooks` member!

Answer (score 2):

I would take the dots off the beginning of the `Workbooks` because `ChartData` doesn't have a `Workbooks` member

Comment: That should do it. Also note the `Sheets` collection can return `Chart` objects, not just `Worksheet` instances - code that means to work with a `Worksheet` should use the `Worksheets` collection instead, else you can expect error 438 when you try to get the `UsedRange` off a `Chart`.

Comment: Like @Mat's Mug said I did get an error when just removing the periods. But I can't seem to figure out how to add Worksheets to my code... Will it still be in the `With` statement? This was the best I could think of: https://pastebin.com/jfMv7NMd but I also tried `Workbooks.Worksheets.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Clear` and `Workbooks.Worksheets.UsedRange.Clear` to no avail :( "Method or data member not found"

Comment: You seem to have no idea what you're doing... `Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Clear`. IntelliSense is telling you what members are available. Listen to it! There's no `Worksheets` member on the `Workbooks` collection. Figure out what `Workbook` you need to work against first.

Comment: I'm sorry @Mat's Mug, but you're not wrong. This is only my 3rd week coding anything, so I'm still learning. Thank you for your patience, and for helping out anyways! So I got past UsedRange.Clear but then I get an error on `Worksheets(1).Range("A2").Select` , so I turned it into: https://pastebin.com/N27qQZLW . Now the code runs and ends... But it's not actually pasting anything into the Graph. Any ideas?

Comment: @Pinlop you probably need to `Copy` the source before you attempt to `Paste` onto a target.

Comment: @Mat's Mug This is what I have written so far: https://pastebin.com/fp34CiJg The Copy happens right before the `With` Statement... `'Copy table
ShWork.UsedRange.Copy ' all the data added to ShWork
With c.ChartData
Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Clear
Worksheets(1).Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With` I have also tried this: `With c.ChartData
.Activate
Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Clear
Worksheets(1).Range("A2").Paste
.Workbooks.Close
End With`

Comment: Move the copy to immediately before the paste, don't select or activate anything between the two operations.

Comment: @Mat's Mug That worked when I added `.Activate` and `.Workbook.Close`! Would you like to post an answer so I can approve it? Thank you sir :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155087/discussion-between-pinlop-and-mats-mug).